# Reading a xml file over GCDAsyncsocket in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I am stuck on a very basic concept here. I have been using GCDAsyncsocket for my project. It's request response kind of a client wherein i get a xml file from a server(Java based) over socket, i read this file save it in App's document directory, parse the request tags send to someone else, get the response to corresponding request and write it to a xml file appending responses after each respective request and sending it back to the server.

I tried reading the file but i am getting the data in bytes i suppose, i am unable to decode that data to appropriate format Can someone help me on how i can read a xml file over socket(GCDAsyncsocket) and save it to my app documents directory

Here is the basic code that i have been using:- 
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

```
NSString *hostAddress = self.serverTextfield.text;
uint16_t port = PORT;

_delegateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.a.cs.delegateQueue", NULL);
asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:_delegateQueue];

DDLogInfo(@"Connecting to %@ on port %hu...", hostAddress, port);

NSError *error = nil;
if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:hostAddress onPort:port error:&error])
{
    DDLogError(@"Oops Error Connecting.. %@",error);
    self.notificationTextView.text = @"Oops Error Connecting";
} else {
    DDLogVerbose(@"Connected");
    self.notificationTextView.text = @"Connected";
}
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *uniqueID = [defaults objectForKey:@"UUID"];

NSLog(@"%@",uniqueID);

 NSUInteger len = [uniqueID lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 Byte buffer[2];
 buffer[0] = (0xff & (len >>8));
 buffer[1] = (0xff & (len));

 NSMutableData *outData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:2];
 [outData appendBytes:buffer length:2];
 [outData appendData:[uniqueID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"%@",outData);
[asyncSocket writeData:outData  withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

}

This is my action method which gets invoked on a button click named "Connect". I write out some data send it to server and start reading data and in the delegate didReadData i do the manipulation of the data i received from the server and again call
[sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0]; so that it continuously listens for the read data...

Now instead of the string data that i am getting from the server i am expecting a XML file which my server would be sending me.. How do i read this file and manipulate it?? Also how can i send a file to the server back which i saved in my Application's Document directory.. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: You have given us little to go on.  By saying that you "tried reading the file" I am concerned that you haven't read the GCDAsyncSocket documentation, "Getting Started" and "Common Pitfalls," and are instead hoping that GCDAsyncSocket has a magical "readXMLstream" method you missed.  Since it doesn't, the concept of reading a file doesn't apply at the level where you are interacting with the library.  Which -readData... method are you using?  What do you do with that data?  And yes, GCDAsyncSocket only sees data, not higher level understanding of that data.

Comment: @tobinijm - I have updated my post above... Sorry for delay !!

Comment: Thanks for providing more info. In general, stackoverflow is here to answer specific questions more of the "why does this code error out?" or "Why is my view always black even though I'm...." variety than questions about approach or code review.  I think you are asking for help with handing the XML data that was sent to you, but you haven't supplied that code.  Saying this is not very helpful to you, so I'm going to post an "answer" that can continue the dialog outside of comments.

Comment: What does your GCDAsyncDelegate method for reading data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would look at, if you haven't already, is the SimpleHTTPClient project that GCDAsyncSocket included in the download.  The XML doctype is the payload inside the HTTP packets, so it's an appropriate project to model yours after.

That said, are you sure your code is sending to your server what the server is expecting?  It is expecting nothing more than a UTF8 string UUID?  It isn't expecting that UUID to be wrapped in XML?  Does the server log incoming connection requests in a way you can see that it is getting what it expects and is actually returning to you XML?

Comment: @tobinjim- I looked into that already... But that is not what i need... I just need a way via which i can send files from Client(iOS) to Server(Java) and vice versa using GCDAsyncSocket.. My final aim is to compare the XML's which server has and which i sent after manipulating at my end.                      So can you be more specific and actually let me know how i can achieve that.. I am really stuck here.

Comment: Well, are you sure that a) The Java server understood your request, b) sent back what you were expecting, and c) GCDAsyncSocket has placed that in the data buffer you are expecting?  If you know all of that to be true, I think you want the NSXMLParser class, starting with the -initWithData: call passing in the NSData that GCDAsyncSocket filled for you.